# Shell scripting to print list of elements

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, sh

Is there any command in shell scripting which is similar to "list" in tcl? I want to write a list of elements to a file  (each in separate line) .But, if the element matches a particular pattern then element next to it and the element itself  should be printed in the same line. Is there any command in shell script for doing this?

example: my string is like " execute the command run abcd.v"
I want to write each word in separate lines of a file but if the word is "run" then abcd.v and run must be printed in the same line. So, the output should be like,

```
execute
the
command
run abcd.v
```

How to do this in shell scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line="execute the command run abcd.v"
for word in $line    # the variable needs to be unquoted to get "word splitting"
do
    case $word in
        run|open|etc) sep=" " ;;  
        *) sep=$'\n' ;;
    esac
    printf "%s%s" $word "$sep"
done
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in bash:

- Name this following script as `list`
- Set it to executable
- Copy it to your `~/bin/`:

`List:`

```
#!/bin/bash
# list

while [[ -n "$1" ]]
do
   if [[ "$1" == "run" ]]; then
       echo "$1 $2"
   else
       echo "$1"
   fi
   shift
done
```

And this is how you can use it on the command prompt:

```
list execute the command run abcd.v > outputfile.txt
```

And your `outputfile.txt` will be written as:

```
execute
the
command
run abcd.v
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish it by using the below script.  It would not be a single command.  Below is a for loop that has an if statment to check for the keyword run.  It does not append a new line character( `echo -n` ).

```
for i in `echo "execute the command run abcd.v"`
do 
  if [ $i = "run" ] ; then  
    echo -n "$i " >> fileOutput
  else 
    echo $i >> fileOutput
  fi
done
```